# iOS programming - calendars

Tags: ios, sdk, icalendar

I'm in the process of creating an app that would use iCal format calendars, most likely stored by Google in Google Calendars.

What's the best approach to achieve this? I don't really want to import my calendars in the iOS calendar app.

Should I got through the hassle to recompile the library of iOS and all that?

Thank you.
Genie

Comment: You need to make this question much more specific before we can help you. Best approach to achieve what, exactly? Recompile what library? All what? I really have no idea what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some sort of code to parse iCal calendars, so it stands to reason that you'll either write that yourself or use somebody else's code. Here's [a SO question that covers building libical for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3115810/643383), with a link to a (possibly) helpful blog entry. The blog does indeed make it sound like a hassle, but as that entry is also several years old and covers iPhoneOS 2.0 (long before it was even called iOS), things may not be so bad.

There's also an [Objective-C wrapper](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CalendarWrapper) which may make using libical that much more pleasant. If you try it, please let us know how it works.

Comment: I looked closer to this and I think the best option if I decide to go with CalDav and google would be HSCalDav, https://github.com/kdbdallas/HSCalDav, this seems to be something that would fit my needs, or use Google Web Engine and build my own calendar and use JSON to access it. This way I won't need the user to have a google account to access it's calendars.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a component to build a Calendar, i think this one will work:

http://code.google.com/p/scm-subversion/source/browse/trunk/iPhone/CalendarTest/Calendar/KLCalendarView.h?spec=svn11&r=11

All months transactions, and UI designs were built and i haven't seen any better components, i think that is worthy for you to take a look.

if you're looking to build your own calendar, you could use this one as example.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, right now I'm looking more for the backend, to read CalDAV calendar items, store them and then use them later.

Comment: Have you any screenshots of your calendar ?

Comment: Actually i build it up on a iphone app. You can check it out here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hy-vee/id479759212?mt=8