# Compiling Libical for arm64 and x86_64 for iOS

Tags: ios, arm64, libical

It took some time for me to compile LibiCal for arm64 and x86_64 architecture for iOS(device and simulator). Thought it may be useful for others. Here is the steps I followed to compile LibiCal-1.0. I have taken code from below link

[Compiling libical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197955/compiling-libical/12613088#12613088)

and modified a bit to suit for Xcode 5.1

1)  download LibiCal from below URL

http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/

Untar and get into libCal-1.0 folder. Then run

./bootstrap

(Need to download make tools from http://www.jattcode.com/installing-autoconf-automake-libtool-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion/ )

Use below script

```
#!/bin/sh

# SEE: http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/libical/

PATH="`xcode-select -print-path`/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"

# set the prefix
PREFIX=${HOME}/Library/libical
OUTPUTDIR=../libical-build

export ARCH=arm64

# Select the desired iPhone SDK
export SDKVER="7.1"
export DEVROOT=`xcode-select --print-path`
export  SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVER}.sdk
export IOSROOT=$DEVROOT/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform

# Includes
# find $DEVROOT -type d -name include|grep -i iphone|grep -i arm-apple-darwin|grep -vi    install-tools|grep -vi simulator

# $SDKROOT/usr/include
# $DEVROOT/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include

if [ ! -d $DEVROOT ]
then
        echo "Developer Root not found! - $DEVROOT"
        exit
fi

echo "DEVROOT = $DEVROOT"

if [ ! -d $SDKROOT ]
then
        echo "SDK Root not found! - $SDKROOT"
        exit
fi

echo "SDKROOT = $SDKROOT"

if [ ! -d $IOSROOT ]
then
        echo "iOS Root not found! - $IOSROOT"
        exit
fi

echo "IOSROOT = $IOSROOT"

# finding ld
# find $DEVROOT -type f -name ld|grep -i iphone

# Set up relevant environment variables 
export CPPFLAGS="-arch $ARCH -I$SDKROOT/usr/include -I$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include"
export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -arch $ARCH"

export CLANG=$DEVROOT/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang

#export CC=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2
#export CXX=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2

export CC=$CLANG
export CXX=$CLANG
export LD=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/ld
export AR=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/ar 
export AS=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/as 
export LIBTOOL=$IOSROOT/usr/bin/libtool 
export STRIP=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/strip 
export RANLIB=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib

HOST=arm-apple-darwin10

if [ ! -f $CC ]
then
        echo "C Compiler not found! - $CC"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -f $CXX ]
then
        echo "C++ Compiler not found! - $CXX"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -f $LD ]
then
        echo "Linker not found! - $LD"
        exit
fi

if [ -d $OUTPUTDIR/$ARCH ]
then 
       rm -rf $OUTPUTDIR/$ARCH
fi

find . -name \*.a -exec rm {} \;
make clean

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --disable-dependency-tracking --host $HOST CXX=$CXX CC=$CC LD=$LD AR=$AR AS=$AS LIBTOOL=$LIBTOOL STRIP=$STRIP RANLIB=$RANLIB

make -j4

# copy the files to the arch folder

mkdir -p $OUTPUTDIR
mkdir -p $OUTPUTDIR/$ARCH

cp `find . -name \*.a` $OUTPUTDIR/$ARCH/

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info $OUTPUTDIR/$ARCH/*.a

echo $ARCH DONE

echo "See $OUTPUTDIR"
```

modify the line:11 "export ARCH=arm64" to get desired architecture, i.e. arm64, armv7, armv7s.

This should create bins for desired architecture in ../libical-build folder.

## Building for x86_64.

Use following commands to run get build for x86_64.

```
tar -xovf libical-1.0.tar
cd libical-1.0
./bootstrap
./configure
make
```

This should create libical.a in folder src/libical/.libs/libical.a.

## Creating a fat library

Use below command to build the fat library. (Please use appropriate lipo command).

```
export DEVROT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lip

$DEVROOT/usr/bin/lipo 
    -arch arm64 $OUTPUTDIR/armv6/libical.a 
    -arch i386 $OUTPUTDIR/i386/libical_Simulator.a 
    -arch armv7 $OUTPUTDIR/x86_64/libical.a 
    -arch armv7s $OUTPUTDIR/x86_64/libical.a 
    -arch x86_64 $OUTPUTDIR/x86_64/libical.a 
    -create -output $OUTPUTDIR/libical_fat_universal.a
```

Please set appropriate OUTPUTDIR environment variable.

I hope above will help some one who wants to quickly build Libical for iOS.

Comment: iOS and x86_64?  What device is that then?

Comment: Also that is a really sub-optimal way of doing it.  Use `xcrun` with the `-sdk` option and you can forget about `$PATH`, `$SYSROOT` and that other rubbish.

Comment: x86_64 for iPhone 64 bit simulator

Comment: Hi Girish, this was very useful - thanks for posting this!

Comment: One question - how does one get the i386 libical.a? For me, the compilation stops with _"fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]"_. The file is also named differently. Any steps for that?

Comment: @trojanfoe would love to see your answer using xcrun.

Comment: @user1514989 I can't seem to build i386 or x86_64 libraries that I can then feed into the lipo command that creates one complete fat library.  Bueler, Bueler?

Comment: This does not seem to work with the latest libical library from github, which has moved to cmake. Can anyone please provide an updated build script?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a fix for the issue.  The main thing I did was add the following switch

```
-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0
```

Here is my current version of the script:

```
 #!/bin/sh

set -o xtrace

# SEE: http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/libical/

PATH="`xcode-select -print-path`/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"


if [ ! -n "$ARCH" ]; then
    export ARCH=armv7
fi


# Select the desired iPhone SDK
export SDKVER="7.1"
export DEVROOT=`xcode-select --print-path`

if [ "i386" = $ARCH ] || [ "x86_64" = $ARCH ]; then
    export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator${SDKVER}.sdk
    export MIOS="-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0"
else
    export SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVER}.sdk
    export MIOS=""
fi;
export IOSROOT=$DEVROOT/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform



if [ ! -d $DEVROOT ]
then
        echo "Developer Root not found! - $DEVROOT"
        exit 1
fi

echo "DEVROOT = $DEVROOT"

if [ ! -d $SDKROOT ]
then
        echo "SDK Root not found! - $SDKROOT"
        exit 1
fi

echo "SDKROOT = $SDKROOT"

if [ ! -d $IOSROOT ]
then
        echo "iOS Root not found! - $IOSROOT"
        exit 1
fi

echo "IOSROOT = $IOSROOT"

# Set up relevant environment variables 
export CPPFLAGS="-arch $ARCH -I$SDKROOT/usr/include $MIOS --debug"
export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT "
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -arch $ARCH"

export CLANG=$DEVROOT/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang


export CC=$CLANG
export CXX=$CLANG
export LD=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/ld
export AR=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/ar 
export AS=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/as 
export LIBTOOL=$IOSROOT/usr/bin/libtool 
export STRIP=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/strip 
export RANLIB=$IOSROOT/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib
export LIPO="xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo"
export HOST=arm-apple-darwin10


if [ ! -f $CC ]
then
        echo "C Compiler not found! - $CC"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -f $CXX ]
then
        echo "C++ Compiler not found! - $CXX"
        exit
fi

if [ ! -f $LD ]
then
        echo "Linker not found! - $LD"
        exit
fi

if [ -d $OUTPUT_DIR/$ARCH ]
then 
       rm -rf $OUTPUT_DIR/$ARCH
fi

find ./src -name \*.a -exec rm {} \;
make clean


./configure --prefix="$OUTPUT_DIR" --disable-dependency-tracking --host $HOST CXX=$CXX CC=$CC LD=$LD AR=$AR AS=$AS LIBTOOL=$LIBTOOL STRIP=$STRIP RANLIB=$RANLIB

make -j4

# copy the files to the arch folder

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR/$ARCH

cp `find . -name \*.a` $OUTPUT_DIR/$ARCH/
cp config.log $OUTPUT_DIR/$ARCH/config.log

$LIPO -info $OUTPUT_DIR/$ARCH/*.a

echo $ARCH DONE

echo "See $OUTPUT_DIR"
```

I've started building out a Objective C wrapper for this library and you can see the progress at
https://github.com/ahalls/XbICalendar  I the project could use some eyeballs with suggestions and even some help.

Answer (score 0):

Those looking to compile the latest version of libical using cmake (from github) for iOS, please checkout my answer here:

[Compiling libical for armv7 and arm64 with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381038/compiling-libical-for-armv7-and-arm64-with-cmake/29392109#29392109)