# Compiling libical for armv7 and arm64 with cmake

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, arm64, libical

I've gone through the various solutions of compiling libical v1.0 for armv7, however the latest libical library available on github seems to have moved to cmake:

https://github.com/libical/libical

Can someone please guide me as to what I should be doing to get this to compile for iOS and Mac (one fat static library)? I've been able to compile it for the Mac but don't know how to do the same for armv7 and arm64. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything from ios-toolchain for cmake to writing a build script myself. Nothing worked. In the end it turned out to be simple. Simply run cmake and compile libical on a 64-bit Mac. Then take all the produced code from under the "src" directory and add that straight to your iOS project. Then, replace #include  with #include "config.h" globally and disable ICU support. Add a preprocessor macro to your build settings to include the generated config.h